# componentsSeparatedByString return wrong result

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring

I used this code to cut the string

```
    NSString *titleString = @"22.225453615805794,113.554006577014889";
    NSArray *array = [titleString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"title string %@", titleString);
    NSLog(@"first %.15f", [[array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"second %.15f", [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]);
```

but why it return

22.225454330444336
and
113.554008483886719

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because floating point numbers are not that accurate, you can get a higher accuracy by calling `doubleValue` instead of `floatValue`:

```
NSLog(@"second %.15f", [[array objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]);
```

This is not a problem with `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem in converting string into float. Try using double.